# Why chrome doesn't input saved password when content script clicks login button(from chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I made a chrome extension where if certain conditions occur it navigates you to logging page. Chrome automatically fills input fields with saved login and password, and **content script** clicks "login" button, but the page states that "login and password field can't be empty". Script that executes on this page is just:  `document.getElementById('submit_button').click();`. I tried making script wait few seconds before executing, but it doesn't help. Is chrome prohibiting script to login with saved login details? Is there some workaroud, to force chrome to behave the same way as a user would click login button manually?

EDIT: Fields are filled in by chrome before my script clicks login, and I tried to focus/click any input field.

Comment: Chrome often doesn't fill in the login fields until you click on one of them. Try giving focus to the login or password field before submitting.

Comment: When you wait a few seconds, do you see the fields filled in?

Comment: Yes, they are filled in. And I tried clicking/focusing input fields before clicking, still doesn't work

Comment: For me it looks like a timing issue. You could check the value of the Input and only click If prefilled, otherwise start timeout to try it a Bit later.